# Call the EIMI in the base type from the EIMI of the derived type

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface

Are there any alternatives if I decide to cast the base keyword to an interface?

The following code won`t work due to the compile-time error:

> Use of keyword 'base' is not valid in this context [Console.NET]csharp(CS0175)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace myprogram
{
    public interface I
    {
        void foo();
    }

    public class B : I
    {
        void I.foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("in B foo");
        }
    }

    public class D : B, I
    {
        void I.foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("in D foo");
            I i = base;
            i.foo();
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            I d = new D();
            d.foo();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I want to get the following output:

```
in D foo
in B foo
```

using the `I` interface and the `D` type being derived from the `B`.

Or is it impossible to call the EIMI in the base type from the EIMI of the derived type?

Comment: Because they're both explicitly implemented, the derived one's interface completely overwrites the base one for derived-class instances. Normally, you would do `((B)this).foo()`, but that can't target an explicitly implemented interface member. You can't do `((I)(B)this).foo()` because the cast back to `I` would get the derived class's implementation.

Comment: Is there a reason you're implementing `foo` explicitly? If you implement it *implicitly*, you can do `base.foo()` and get the output you desire. And that's easier to do than what you're doing here.

Comment: @madreflection, no. There are no reasons except that I am just learning. Thank you for your comments and attention.

Comment: Makes sense. Explicit implementation is intended to serve 2 purposes. 1) (most importantly) to resolve conflicts when implementing two interfaces that have members with identical signatures, and 2) to implement interface members without making them part of the type's public interface, i.e. you have to cast to the interface to access them.

Comment: @madreflection, a useful note. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no possible to use `base` in such form in C# `I i = base;`. You can use `base.foo()`, but it doesn't work with explicit interface implementation, as explained in OP comments.

The possible workaround of this can be adding a helper virtual method and overriding it in derived class (and removing explicit implementation in second class)

```cs
public class B : I
{
    void I.foo()
    {
        Bar();
    }

    protected virtual void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in B foo");
    }
}

public class D : B
{
    protected override void Bar()
    {
        base.Bar();
        Console.WriteLine("in D foo");
    }
}
```

Output will be the following

```
in B foo 
in D foo
```

There is also a simpler option without explicit interface implementation

```cs
public class B : I
{
    public virtual void foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in B foo");
    }
}

public class D : B
{
    public override void foo()
    {
        base.foo();
        Console.WriteLine("in D foo");
    }
}
```